# How to consolidate data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formulas

I have an excel table that has 3 columns, one is date, the other is time, and the third is a numerical value, see below:

```
DATE          TIME      VALUE
01/01/2013    13:00     1
01/01/2013    13:00     1
01/01/2013    13:00     3
01/01/2013    13:30     1
01/01/2013    13:30     1
02/01/2013    13:00     2
02/01/2013    13:00     1
02/01/2013    13:30     2
```

What I would like to do is consolidate this table in such a way that whenever the date and time match, I would sum up the values column, therfore the end result should be like this.

```
DATE          TIME      VALUE
01/01/2013    13:00     5
01/01/2013    13:00     5
01/01/2013    13:00     5
01/01/2013    13:30     2
01/01/2013    13:30     2
02/01/2013    13:00     3
02/01/2013    13:00     3
02/01/2013    13:30     2
```

Once this is done, I can remove duplicates and have a shorter table like this:

```
DATE          TIME      VALUE
01/01/2013    13:00     5
01/01/2013    13:30     2
02/01/2013    13:00     3
02/01/2013    13:30     2
```

Unfortunately I haven't been able to come up with a formula do do this. Could someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by 'sum up the values column'?

Comment: I mean that I would like to sum the each number on the values column depending if the date and time match, in the example above, the values column is 1, 1, 3 and 1 for the date 01/01/2013 and the time 13:00, therfore I would like to sum these values and add the result, 5, the values column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMIFS() sounds the way to go. It lets you sum one column based on multiple conditions in others.

They syntax runs a little like this... =SUMIF([$Values],[$DataList],[Date],[$TimeList],[Time])

or in context

```
A             B         C      D
DATE          TIME      VALUE
01/01/2013    13:00     1      =SUMIFS($C$2:$C$8,$A$2:$A$8,A3,$B$2:$B$8,B3)
01/01/2013    13:00     1      =SUMIFS($C$2:$C$8,$A$2:$A$8,A4,$B$2:$B$8,B4)
01/01/2013    13:00     3      .
01/01/2013    13:30     1      .
01/01/2013    13:30     1      .
02/01/2013    13:00     2
02/01/2013    13:00     1
02/01/2013    13:30     2
```

There would be quite a lot of duplication of calculation in there but who's looking for elegant

Answer (score 2):

You just need to learn about Pivot Table.

Just select the entire table, click in Pivot table button:

[image]

Just select Columns *Date* and *Time* to "Row label" and Column *Value* to Values. Then in Values change *Count of* to *Sum of*

[image]
[image]